# Custom WPF EndLineCap, StartLineCap & LineJoin or new attached properties

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, controls, attached-properties

Just wondering if anyone knows how I would implement additional/custom EndLineCap, StartLineCap & LineJoin attributes?

In short, LineJoin="Round" is what I want but I need both sides of the angle are smooth - instead of just the wider angled side.

Also, instead of just Rounded EndLineCap and StartLineCap I want a ball on each end (for instance, a circle at each end who's diameter is double that of the with of the line).

Instead of adding additional custom  items, I might be able to achieve this through attached properties, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: [Custom line caps in WPF](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mrochon/archive/2011/01/10/custom-line-caps-in-wpf.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that it is possible to do what you're asking. Line Caps are implemented at a very low level in WPF where there seems to be little possibility of customisation.

The lowest level Graphics API that WPF exposes is the [DrawingContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingcontext.aspx). This provides methods like [DrawLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingcontext.drawline.aspx) which take a [Pen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pen.aspx) object to specify how LineCaps should be drawn. Your choice of LineCaps is limited to those exposed in the [PenLineCap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.penlinecap.aspx) enum - it doesn't provide a "Custom" option.

Having said all that, it may be possible to emulate custom line caps by modifying the path data in a geometry. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641941/wpf-line-path-etc-drawing-style) may give you some hints.