# Custom Shapes with Custom Borders in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have to draw some custom shapes in wpf, like Square, Ellipse, Spade etc etc as shown in the image.

Now I need to apply some simple borders to those shapes like shown in the image,

How should I achieve it. Shape size id variable, it could be small, medium, large and extra large.

[image]

what I have done till now is draw all the images using this

```
Ellipse
<Ellipse Width='4' Height='4' Stroke='Green' Fill='Red'>

Triangle
<Polygon Points='2 0, 4 4,0 4' Stroke='Green' Fill='Red'>

Spade
<Polygon Points='2 0, 4 2,2 4,0 2' Stroke='Green' Fill='Red'> and so on.
```

The first border with simple line is not a problem. I could use a simple border or just change the size of stroke so they show they have a border, problem lies in dashed lines and double lines border

Comment: I will blindly downvote and close-vote any and all questions with the `[wpf]` tag without even reading them unless they explicitly contain relevant code and meet the **What Have You Tried???** requirement. I'm getting tired of linking to [**This Post**](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) on almost every single WPF question in StackOverflow.

Comment: @HighCore Thanks for great sentimental speech on the criteria of wpf questions, can you please answer it now when the question has been updated and satisfy the criteria of being a wpf question.

Answer (score 0):

Check a set of Stroke... properties of [Shape class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.shapes.shape%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

StrokeThickness - to set thickness,

StrokeDashArray - to setup dashed pattern

Regarding last two items in second drop down - I do not see an easy way of implementing such border for any generic shape. 
[**Update**] Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641941/wpf-line-path-etc-drawing-style) it contains some ideas applicable to your situation